# Application Has Stopped Unexpectedly,

Tags: android, tabs, logcat, android-logcat, android-tabs

I do not know how to intepreet the log cat so a little help will be much appreciated. In my application, I have added all the classes in my Android.Manifest. I do not have errors in my code but when I run the application on the emulator, a dialog box pops up saying that "The application has stopped unexpectedly" What could be the problem?

```
03-18 01:01:04.362: D/AndroidRuntime(271): Shutting down VM
03-18 01:01:04.362: W/dalvikvm(271): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gormahia/com.example.gormahia.TabMain}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab content
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab content
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:199)
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.example.gormahia.TabMain.onCreate(TabMain.java:44)
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  ... 11 more
03-18 01:06:04.472: I/Process(271): Sending signal. PID: 271 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Post your code from `TabMain` class the method `onCreate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line give you informations about the problem `"you must specify a way to create the tab content"`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gormahia/com.example.gormahia.TabMain}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab content
03-18 01:01:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(271):
```

com.example.gormahia.TabMain: on line 44

```
 at com.example.gormahia.TabMain.onCreate(TabMain.java:44)
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right, i had forgotten to set the Content in the tabs. Thanks alot..